# Django settings module...not possible to run the logger?

Tags: python, django, logging

I use the python `logging` module in my `my_app/views.py` file with no problem.

I tried to use it inside the `staging_settings.py` that I use for my configuration. But the messages never reach the error log, whilst the messages from the `views.py` work fine.

my `staging_settings.py`:

```
LOGGING= { ..redacted for space.. } # the logging config-dict 

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug(F"this is staging_ setup")
```

Is it just an impossibility to run a logger inside a `setup.py`? I guess the server actually isn't running yet, so there is nothing for the logger to send to?  I'm running this on pythonanywhere, so I don't really have a console to simply `print()` to or some other hack alternative.

Comment: Did you check already log level / handler / stream for the logger with name `__name__`?

Comment: `print()` on PythonAnywhere should wind up in your server log (linked from the "Web" tab.

Comment: @GilesThomas Yes, thanks, that works fine.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging isn't configured at the time the settings file is imported, so you can't do logging from the module level in it. The sequence is

1. Django imports the settings from your `staging_settings.py`
2. Django fetches the LOGGING dict with the configuration from that imported module
3. Django configures `logging` with the configuration
4. When you log anything after that, `logging` then starts to output stuff as per your configuration

You can't expect to log and get log output in step 1.

**Update:** AFAIK there's no Django-version-independent way of determining when logging has been configured. You could define your own filter which sets a flag when instantiated, which would happen during configuration. Anyway, that doesn't help you if you need to log from the settings module in module-level code. However, functions that are defined in the settings module and are called later (after logging configuration has happened) can do logging.

Comment: At what point does the  `logging` package actually 'come to life' then? I don't know the right terminology, but it seems that at the point in Django startup where it's reading the `settings.py`,  logging is not ready to operate.